# How can I slice a images to 9 part and then save crop images into specific folder? (in python)

Tags: python

**The problem is:** I can slice my images into 9 parts but I can't save them in a specific folder. I want to save my slice images into a specific location.

**my code is here:**

```
import cv2    
import os  
import glob  
import numpy as np      
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt      
from scipy.misc import imsave          
from scipy import ndimage  
from scipy import misc  
import scipy.misc  
import scipy  
import image_slicer  
from image_slicer import join  
from PIL import Image  
import imageio  
from PIL import Image  


PATH = 'C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Slice'  
os.listdir(PATH)  

images=glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH,'eye_images','*.tif'))  

cropheight=200  
cropwidth = 200  
k=-1  
for file in images:  
    k+=1  
    im = Image.open(images[k])  
    width, height = im.size  
    for i in range(0, width, cropwidth):  
     for j in range(0, height, cropheight):   
       box = (i, j,i+cropwidth, j+cropheight)  
       print('%s %s' % (images[k], box))  
       im.crop(box).save('%s.width%03d.height%03d.tif' % (images[k], i, j))
```

Comment: what actual result or error are you getting? Please also remove the unnecessary parts of your code to provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: when I run this code for an image dataset, I get 9 slices of images for 1 image.
the problem is all of the slice images save in the same folder. I want to save all slices of images in a different locations.

Comment: The last line in your snippet determines the location - why not just change the path there?

Comment: I changed it.. but it's not working!! can you do it? please!!